# doubling property on manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I am learning the *Geometric Measure Theory*, and curious about how to generalize the covering lemma on manifold. However I am stuck at the doubling property:

*Let $(X,d,\mu)$ be a metric space with measure. If there exists a constant $C$, satisfies 
$$\mu(B(x,2r))\leq C\mu(B(x,r)),$$
then we call $X$ satisfies doubling property.*

Which Riemannian manifold satisfies doubling space? Is there any condition on manifold?

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the definition by asserting that given the doubling property above, $\exists C, \kappa \geq 0$ such that $\forall x \in M, r \geq 0$ and $\theta \geq 1$, $B(x, \theta r) \leq C \theta^{\kappa} B(x, r)$.

This exactly shows that given a manifold $M$ and its associated geodesic distance and measure; is a space of homogeneous type. The spaces of Coifmann and Weiss that extend the use of Hardy spaces would contain these type. See [Extensions of Hardy Spaces and their use in Analysis](https://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/open_files/2282_CoifmanWeiss.pdf).

Further to this, if the manifold $M$ has non-negative Ricci curvature then the above doubling space condition holds. For a comprehensive review of this particular property see Lott and Villani [Weak Curvature Conditions and Functional Inequalities](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506481.pdf).